# Почему jquery element.attr() не срабатывают стили?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть модалка:

```
<div class="reconciliation-modal col-sm-5">
    <div class="modal-header col-sm-12">
        <div class="row main-modal-header">
            <h2 class="col-sm-8">Reconcile</h2>
            <button class="close-btn">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-semi-header row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">Date</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">Description</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Currency</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Amount</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Reconciled</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-semi-header-content row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">07-09-2017</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">Deposit G4S - 0123456789</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">EURO</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">14.055,00</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-droppable-area col-sm-12">Drag transactions here</div>
    <div class="modal-footer row">
        <button class="modal-btn-save col-sm-3">Save & Close</button>
        <div class="float-right col-sm-4">Discrepancy: <span class="discrepancy-sum">3.650</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть код `jQuery`:

```
$('.close-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.reconciliation-modal').attr('display','none;');
})
```

Атрибут в `html` появляется, но не воздействует на модалку(она не пропадает). Вопрос: почему?
**P.S.**
Стили для модалки:

```
.reconciliation-modal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 15%;
    top:30%;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    max-height: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.reconciliation-modal .close-btn {
float: right;
text-align: right;
}
.reconciliation-modal .modal-droppable-area {
padding-top: 25%;
padding-bottom: 25%;
text-align: center;
background: #cacaca;
}
```

Comment: потому что это не атрибут `$('.reconciliation-modal').css('display','none');`  или `$('.reconciliation-modal').hide();`

Comment: @Igor Оформи как ответ, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что это не атрибут

```
$('.reconciliation-modal').css('display','none');
```

или

```
$('.reconciliation-modal').hide();
```